# Is there an alternative for samepage for a multicolumn environment?

Tags: sectioning, page-breaking, two-column, widows-orphans

In my document, I successfully use samepage to force content to be on the same page. I want to do the same in a 2-column document so that the heading and the text are in the same column. How can I achieve that?

Here is my MWE. I want to force the heading Test to be on on the second column, or more text after the heading on the left column.

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}

\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse fermentum turpis sed nunc porttitor posuere. Nunc accumsan rutrum nisi ac varius. Donec nibh dolor, dignissim sit amet dictum et, iaculis at nunc. Nunc non gravida nulla. Phasellus et risus rutrum, facilisis quam sit amet, fermentum tortor. Nulla vel nisi mattis, tempor orci et, luctus tellus. Pellentesque mauris nibh, pretium ac tincidunt non, vulputate id lectus. Pellentesque blandit justo nisl, ut rhoncus dui gravida eget. Fusce accumsan egestas placerat. Quisque aliquet fermentum ex, in dignissim massa. Mauris scelerisque maximus augue eu lacinia. Nam vel porta arcu.

Sed feugiat velit a ultricies luctus. Maecenas ullamcorper pellentesque semper. Maecenas at nisl viverra, vehicula libero in, feugiat nulla. Nulla sit amet mi interdum, tempus arcu eu, suscipit dolor. Nulla erat tortor, commodo finibus ornare nec, sollicitudin sed lectus. Donec nec facilisis velit. Phasellus ultrices metus quis erat vehicula, eu tincidunt mi imperdiet. Vivamus in justo ut lacus viverra ullamcorper. Morbi sit amet nulla ipsum.

Phasellus ultrices lorem eget ante varius, a rutrum mauris egestas. Donec laoreet nunc ex, at semper urna fermentum nec. Curabitur et elit felis. Phasellus interdum, augue non pulvinar commodo, dui neque fermentum felis, ut blandit nibh leo eget magna. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin libero lacus, dapibus at ultricies vitae, malesuada convallis augue. Proin non consectetur tellus. Morbi consequat est ipsum, quis ultricies massa luctus id. Mauris cursus ante turpis, eu efficitur eros imperdiet non. Sed sit amet mauris eleifend ligula auctor facilisis. Aenean pellentesque nunc urna, sed luctus nulla faucibus quis. Praesent et mauris nisi. Phasellus at risus ac erat finibus viverra a nec tellus. Pellentesque mollis libero et egestas tempor. Sed quis diam velit. Integer lorem quam, tristique non nunc sit amet, pharetra iaculis nisi.

Nulla facilisi. Nam lacinia vehicula lectus, porta aliquet nibh gravida a. Mauris tristique odio a est sollicitudin, ac suscipit felis pulvinar. In ultrices eleifend libero eget rhoncus. Etiam et purus pellentesque, imperdiet ex laoreet, placerat libero. Fusce rhoncus tristique congue. Integer at imperdiet arcu, et laoreet massa. Donec sit amet mattis odio, sed placerat magna. Sed odio leo, faucibus sed lorem at, sodales feugiat erat. Mauris fringilla lorem a volutpat interdum. Donec laoreet ullamcorper magna, at molestie est porta id. Vivamus scelerisque accumsan nunc vitae dignissim. Maecenas ullamcorper venenatis consequat. Maecenas vel mauris sed augue vulputate fermentum. Nullam porta vel sapien vel hendrerit.

Aliquam at tempor purus. Proin enim nunc, semper pellentesque diam at, facilisis scelerisque magna. Nunc ac commodo urna, eu laoreet eros. Phasellus eros eros, scelerisque cursus pellentesque tincidunt, volutpat sed diam. Donec accumsan arcu vel interdum lobortis. Maecenas sagittis condimentum felis ut rutrum. Vivamus hendrerit nisl a tristique dictum. Vivamus tristique blandit justo nec blandit. Praesent egestas enim quis eros facilisis tempor. Quisque in neque in metus interdum ornare. Nunc mattis in quam ac euismod. Maecenas faucibus nisl justo, in tempus sem ornare a. Aenean non elit nec elit fermentum laoreet et id ipsum. Duis euismod sollicitudin leo eu mollis. Sed consequat diam id magna malesuada pulvinar.

\section{Test}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse fermentum turpis sed nunc porttitor posuere. Nunc accumsan rutrum nisi ac varius. Donec nibh dolor, dignissim sit amet dictum et, iaculis at nunc. Nunc non gravida nulla. Phasellus et risus rutrum, facilisis quam sit amet, fermentum tortor. Nulla vel nisi mattis, tempor orci et, luctus tellus. Pellentesque mauris nibh, pretium ac tincidunt non, vulputate id lectus. Pellentesque blandit justo nisl, ut rhoncus dui gravida eget. Fusce accumsan egestas placerat. Quisque aliquet fermentum ex, in dignissim massa. Mauris scelerisque maximus augue eu lacinia. Nam vel porta arcu.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In what sense is that code *minimal*? Minimal means: if you remove even one of those packages from the preamble, the problem is solved i.e. *all* are required to reproduce the problem. Is that really the case? Also, can you reproduce the issue with a standard class? If not - i.e. if the problem is in the class itself or results from interaction with it - we need to know where to find the class.

Comment: @cfr Ok, got it and I reduced the MWE. Thanks! The class can be found here: https://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sig-alternate.cls

Comment: If you get that output with just the standard class, don't change it. The journal or conference will deal with it, and it is better not to second-guess their preferred solution since you'll doubtless guess wrongly (how could you do otherwise?) and they'll just undo your modifications. Just leave it and let them worry about it. Chances are that they are going to use a different font anyway, and then the break is unlikely to come at the same point anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `\filbreak` or a variation of that.  `\filbreak` is defined to be `\vfil\penalty-200\vfilneg`, but in your example the penalty needs to be more negative; `\vfil\penalty-1000\vfilneg` works.  This will make the first column ragged bottom.  It works by adding some stretchable vertical space, then providing a good break point; if the break point is used then the `\vfilneg` does nothing, if the break point is not used, then the add stretchable vertical space is cancelled out.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{sig-alternate}

\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse fermentum turpis sed nunc porttitor posuere. Nunc accumsan rutrum nisi ac varius. Donec nibh dolor, dignissim sit amet dictum et, iaculis at nunc. Nunc non gravida nulla. Phasellus et risus rutrum, facilisis quam sit amet, fermentum tortor. Nulla vel nisi mattis, tempor orci et, luctus tellus. Pellentesque mauris nibh, pretium ac tincidunt non, vulputate id lectus. Pellentesque blandit justo nisl, ut rhoncus dui gravida eget. Fusce accumsan egestas placerat. Quisque aliquet fermentum ex, in dignissim massa. Mauris scelerisque maximus augue eu lacinia. Nam vel porta arcu.

Sed feugiat velit a ultricies luctus. Maecenas ullamcorper pellentesque semper. Maecenas at nisl viverra, vehicula libero in, feugiat nulla. Nulla sit amet mi interdum, tempus arcu eu, suscipit dolor. Nulla erat tortor, commodo finibus ornare nec, sollicitudin sed lectus. Donec nec facilisis velit. Phasellus ultrices metus quis erat vehicula, eu tincidunt mi imperdiet. Vivamus in justo ut lacus viverra ullamcorper. Morbi sit amet nulla ipsum.

Phasellus ultrices lorem eget ante varius, a rutrum mauris egestas. Donec laoreet nunc ex, at semper urna fermentum nec. Curabitur et elit felis. Phasellus interdum, augue non pulvinar commodo, dui neque fermentum felis, ut blandit nibh leo eget magna. Aliquam erat volutpat. Proin libero lacus, dapibus at ultricies vitae, malesuada convallis augue. Proin non consectetur tellus. Morbi consequat est ipsum, quis ultricies massa luctus id. Mauris cursus ante turpis, eu efficitur eros imperdiet non. Sed sit amet mauris eleifend ligula auctor facilisis. Aenean pellentesque nunc urna, sed luctus nulla faucibus quis. Praesent et mauris nisi. Phasellus at risus ac erat finibus viverra a nec tellus. Pellentesque mollis libero et egestas tempor. Sed quis diam velit. Integer lorem quam, tristique non nunc sit amet, pharetra iaculis nisi.

Nulla facilisi. Nam lacinia vehicula lectus, porta aliquet nibh gravida a. Mauris tristique odio a est sollicitudin, ac suscipit felis pulvinar. In ultrices eleifend libero eget rhoncus. Etiam et purus pellentesque, imperdiet ex laoreet, placerat libero. Fusce rhoncus tristique congue. Integer at imperdiet arcu, et laoreet massa. Donec sit amet mattis odio, sed placerat magna. Sed odio leo, faucibus sed lorem at, sodales feugiat erat. Mauris fringilla lorem a volutpat interdum. Donec laoreet ullamcorper magna, at molestie est porta id. Vivamus scelerisque accumsan nunc vitae dignissim. Maecenas ullamcorper venenatis consequat. Maecenas vel mauris sed augue vulputate fermentum. Nullam porta vel sapien vel hendrerit.

Aliquam at tempor purus. Proin enim nunc, semper pellentesque diam at, facilisis scelerisque magna. Nunc ac commodo urna, eu laoreet eros. Phasellus eros eros, scelerisque cursus pellentesque tincidunt, volutpat sed diam. Donec accumsan arcu vel interdum lobortis. Maecenas sagittis condimentum felis ut rutrum. Vivamus hendrerit nisl a tristique dictum. Vivamus tristique blandit justo nec blandit. Praesent egestas enim quis eros facilisis tempor. Quisque in neque in metus interdum ornare. Nunc mattis in quam ac euismod. Maecenas faucibus nisl justo, in tempus sem ornare a. Aenean non elit nec elit fermentum laoreet et id ipsum. Duis euismod sollicitudin leo eu mollis. Sed consequat diam id magna malesuada pulvinar.

\vfil\penalty-1000\vfilneg
\section{Test}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse fermentum turpis sed nunc porttitor posuere. Nunc accumsan rutrum nisi ac varius. Donec nibh dolor, dignissim sit amet dictum et, iaculis at nunc. Nunc non gravida nulla. Phasellus et risus rutrum, facilisis quam sit amet, fermentum tortor. Nulla vel nisi mattis, tempor orci et, luctus tellus. Pellentesque mauris nibh, pretium ac tincidunt non, vulputate id lectus. Pellentesque blandit justo nisl, ut rhoncus dui gravida eget. Fusce accumsan egestas placerat. Quisque aliquet fermentum ex, in dignissim massa. Mauris scelerisque maximus augue eu lacinia. Nam vel porta arcu.

\end{document}
```